# Display Opening Hours for today even if Venue is still closed

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

`venues`

- id
- venue_name

`hours_of_operation`

- opening_day *(Mon, Tue, Wed...)*
- opening_time
- closing_time
- is_closed *(boolean)*

The hours or operation are usually between `10PM to 03AM` or so meaning that when I check the page at tuesday 01AM, I still need to see the opening hours for Monday and not tuesday.

A nice member helped me out with that and it all works :). I then added some code so that when `is_closed` is `true`, the text "Closed" is displayed.

What this did, however.... is that when a venue opens at `8PM` and it is currently `3PM`, the text "closed" is returned instead. I want it to show the closing hours for that day even if the venue hasn't opened yet.

---

I also wanted to know if it would be possible to show the opening hours of the *previous day* until 5:59AM, and then start showing the opening hours of the current day at 6:00 AM.

*Example:* A venue opens on Monday from 9PM to 04AM, so I will see the closing hours for that venue from Monday 6AM to Tuesday 5:59AM, and so on.... unless it's closed on Monday, in which case the text 'closed' is displayed.

Here's my code:

```
$fullDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

SELECT
venues.ID,
venues.VENUE_NAME,
hrs.opening_day,
hrs.opening_time,
hrs.closing_time,
CASE WHEN (is_closed = 1 or is_closed is null)
       THEN 'closed' 
       ELSE closing_time END AS CLOSING_TIME_OR_CLOSED
FROM venues
LEFT JOIN hours_of_operation hrs
  on hrs.venue_id = venues.id
     and ((hrs.opening_day=date_format('$fullDate' -
           INTERVAL
             (closing_time<opening_time and time('$fullDate')<closing_time)
           DAY, '%a'))
          AND (closing_time<opening_time XOR
         (time('$fullDate') >= least(opening_time,closing_time)
          and time('$fullDate') < greatest(opening_time, closing_time))))
```

...And then I echo `CLOSING_TIME_OR_CLOSED`

Thanks!

---

**Edit** [Please see this schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65fc7/1/1)

As you can see, the first venue is closed and the display is being correctly shown as "closed". The second, however is open, but is still being shown as closed because the set time is `14:30`, while the venue opens at `21:00`. I would like to show the closing time instead of "closed" if the venue hasn't opened yet.

Also, if the time was less than 06:00 AM, I want to show the venues opened from `2013-01-29` instead of `2013-01-30` as some venues are opened late into the night.

Comment: Please show some sample data and the expected result. It's hard to follow you.

Comment: Hey tombom, Please see my edit.